# Table 'restaurant-service.food_menu' doesn't exist

Tags: java, mysql

I need to get all information about restaurant, but when Im doing a request, I have an error   Table 'restaurant-service.food_menu' doesn't exist, so I just don't know how to fix it, but my post request is working excellent [here is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfF9b.png)

Domain

Restaurant

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Restaurant")
    public class Restaurant {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "RESTAURANT_ID")
        private Long id;
    
        private String restaurantName;
    
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "restaurant")
        private List<FoodMenu> menu;
    
        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
        private Address address;
    
    }
```

FoodMenu

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "FoodMenu")
public class FoodMenu {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "FOOD_MENU_ID")
    private Long id;

    private String foodName;

    private String foodDescription;

    private BigDecimal foodPrice;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "RESTAURANT_ID")
    private Restaurant restaurant;

}
```

Service

```
   @Service
    @Transactional
    public class RestaurantService {
        @Autowired
        private RestaurantRepository restaurantRepository;
    
        public void saveRestaurant(Restaurant restaurant){
             restaurantRepository.save(restaurant);
        }
    
        public List<Restaurant> allRestaurants(){
            return restaurantRepository.findAll();
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
 @RestController
    public class RestaurantController {
    
        @Autowired
        private RestaurantService restaurantService;
    
        @PostMapping("/create")
        public void createUploadRestaurant(@RequestBody Restaurant restaurant){
          restaurantService.saveRestaurant(restaurant);
        }
    
        @GetMapping("/showAllRestaurants")
        public List<Restaurant> showRestaurants(){
            return restaurantService.allRestaurants();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name you defined doesn't match what you defined.

```
'restaurant-service.food_menu'  != @Table(name = "FoodMenu")
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "FoodMenu")
public class FoodMenu {
. . . .
```